# How to send extra parameters from page.svelte to page.js inside the same route in Sveltekit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to understand how sveltekit works. Inside my sveltekit demo app, I have `+page.svelte` and `+page.js` files at the same route.

`+page.js`, which gets data from the API, sends data to `+page.svelte`. But it is a one way communication. What if I want to send some parameters to `+page.js`; sth like how many items that I want to show on my page.

I see that `params` only contains slug. And I don't want to use url queries like `/products?limit=10&skip=0`

**page.js**

```js
import { Store } from '@models'

/** @type {import('./$types').PageServerLoad} */
export async function load({params}) {
    // Sth like this:
    let limit = params.limit || 10
    let skip = params.skip || 0
    let res = await Store.get(limit,skip)
    return {
        store: res
    };
};
```

**page.svelte**

```js
export let data
let products = data.store

const loadMore = () => {
    // What to do next???
}
```

```html
{#each products as product}
    {product.title}
{/each}
<button on:click={loadMore}>Load More</button>
```

Is there a way to achieve this? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

See the [advanced routing documentation](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/advanced-routing).

If you do not want to use a query the only alternative is using optional parameters, so you probably should move your route files to something like:

```
src/routes/products/[[skip]]/[[limit]]/+page.svelte
```

This will allow the route to have those two parameters at the end, but they are not required. So all of these routes are valid:

```
/products
/products/1
/products/1/10
```

Parameters that are not provided will not appear in the `params` object. All param values are strings.

Load more items would just be a matter of navigating using `goto`, e.g.

```js
import { goto } from '$app/navigation';
import { page } from '$app/stores';

$: skip = +($page.params.skip ?? 0);
$: limit = +($page.params.limit ?? 10);

const loadMore = () => {
    goto(`/products/${skip + limit}/${limit}`);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I thought about that too, but won't using "goto" cause the page to reload? I assume no shortcuts around here right?

Comment: No, it will not. SvelteKit only loads data if the route is the same. (And even if the route is different, it only loads data that it needs, not everything, e.g. existing layouts are untouched.)

Answer (score 1):

I found a new way of achieving what I really wanted. It still does not seem to be the best solution, but it is the most efficient way for my case right now.

I used the built-in `depends()` function with `invaidate` as [described here](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/types#public-types-loadevent). This way I can update the `data object` for my needs.

So the final code is like below

**page.svelte**

```js
    const loadMore = () => {
        data.loadMore(2)
    }
    const reset = () => {
        data.reset()
    }
```

**page.js**

```js
import { Store } from '@models'
import { invalidate } from '$app/navigation';
let count = 1
/** @type {import('./$types').PageServerLoad} */

export async function load({depends}) {
    let res = await Store.get(count)
    depends('update');
    return {
        store: res,
        count: count,
        loadMore: (e) => {
            invalidate('update');
            count+= e
        },
        reset: () => {
            invalidate('update');
            count = 1
        }
    };
}
```

> ### Important
>
> I did not have much time to test this. **So please read the [documentation](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/types#public-types-loadevent) carefully before using.**
> I would appreciate any comments for this approach.